# getEnabled for a group-Element and not a button?

Tags: c#, ribbonx

I am programming a word addin, which is using a Ribbon.xml.

I can disable a button with the getVisible-Tag.
Is there a way to disable a whole group instead (which contains 9 buttons) or do I have to do it on every single button?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide or show controls using the `getVisible` callback. To disable controls you need to use the `getEnabled` callback instead. Unfortunately the `group` control doesn't provife the `enabled` or `getEnabled` attributes. However, you may find the `visible` or `getVisible` attributes of the group control helpfuil.

Read more about controls and their attributes in the following series of articles in MSDN:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199(v=office.12).aspx)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523(v=office.12).aspx)